# updating multiple records in mongodb using java by filtering and iterating through each record

Tags: java, mongodb-query

i am trying to update a document field by this code , which selects document which have common field value then i am trying to update all those document with some value which is unique for each document

what i have done is this :

```
     for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : maps.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
        FindIterable<Document> iterable1 = docCollection.find(Filters.eq("product_currency", entry.getKey()));
        Iterator<Document> iter1=iterable1.iterator();
        while(iter1.hasNext())
        {
            /*
             * replace previous entry
             */
            Document theObj = iter1.next();

            double retailPrice = (theObj.getDouble("product_price_retail"))/entry.getValue();


            Document doc =new Document("product_price_usd",retailPrice);


            docCollection.updateMany(Filters.eq("product_currency",               entry.getKey()), new Document("$set",doc));
            System.out.println("Doc updated!");
            count++;

        }

    }
```

here my map contains currency rates as follow:

```
HRK : 6.8751
MXN : 18.4137
LVL : 0.6205
LTL : 3.0487
ZAR : 15.9894
INR : 67.825
CNY : 6.5675
THB : 35.52
AUD : 1.4099
ILS : 3.8809
KRW : 1209.145
JPY : 117.415
PLN : 3.9583
GBP : 0.6887
```

but when this update runs all document have same field value. i failed to find any issue why this happening please suggest me some solution.

thanks in advance